# Azure Web App: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate2

My app encounters "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist" exception during the creation of a X509Certificate2.

Function to read cert from Azure Key Vault:

```
 private string GetEncryptSecret(string certConfigName)
    {
        var kv = new KeyVaultClient(GetToken);
        var sec = kv.GetSecretAsync(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[certConfigName]).Result;
        return sec.Value;
    }
```

How I create the new X509Certificate2 object:

```
 public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(CertificatesEnum certificate)
    {
        switch (certificate)
        {
            case CertificatesEnum.Accounts:
                return new X509Certificate2(
                    Convert.FromBase64String(GetEncryptSecret(Constants.Magda.Certificates.Accounts)),
                    string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        }
     }
```

After noticing that this was only working for the first 3-9 requests I've started an Azure Remote Debugging session and saw that the new certificate.Privatekey caused the "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist" exception.

Temporary fixed this by the implementation of a waiting loop because after a couple of retries the new certificate will be created without exception.

```
public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(CertificatesEnum certificate)
    {
        switch (certificate)
        {
            case CertificatesEnum.Accounts:
                var accountCertRawData = Convert.FromBase64String(GetEncryptSecret(Constants.Magda.Certificates.Accounts));
                X509Certificate2 accountCert = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        accountCert= new X509Certificate2(accountCertRawData , string.Empty,
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
                        //set variable to test exception
                        var accountCert = accountCert.PrivateKey;
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000 * i);
                    }
                }
                return accountCert;
          }
    }
```

Does anyone has a proper solution for this and can explain what is happening in the background on the Azure Web app?

Comment: The fact that it works itself out is confusing.  If you used `ondernemingCert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` it should work without the exception (but almost certainly will not return an `RSACryptoServiceProvider`)

Comment: I've tried that as well but GetRSAPrivateKey() throws the same exception.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Have you maybe found the solution @SanderLesage ?

Comment: Also interested in finding a solution. This is happening intermittently on my Azure Web App, and there's no definitive solutions anywhere. I'm desperate enough to use the `temporary fix` above!! @SanderLesage @Xatep

Answer (score 0):

Try removing WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE application setting (if available) from the web application.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure WebApp what seams to fix for me the issue with "some times" throws `Keyset does not exist` when calling `GetPrivateKey()` was not to use `MachineKeySet` for storage flags argument in constructor of `X509Certificate2`

```
new X509Certificate2(certContent, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
```